# Hover over element is working only once, using move_to_element().perform()

Tags: python, selenium, hover, action

I am using Selenium, Python to hover over a warning icon and get the tool tip. I have used ActionChains.
Hover action is succesfull for the first time. The same code is failing while hovering over another warning icon. (If I remove the first hover action, the second hover action is successful, i.e., hover action is performed only once).
Error I am getting :  selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Code snippet:

```
action = ActionChains(self.driver)
Warning_icon = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/i[@class='fa fa-exclamation-circle']")
assert Warning_icon 
action.move_to_element(Warning_icon) .perform()
TooltipMessage = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("").text
action.release()
```

Edit1:
The hover is happening over the same warning messages, even when other elements are mentioned in move_to_element(other_element).
How to make the mouse hover over new elements?
action.release() doesnot seem to work here.

Comment: Though not the correct way, but the only way I can hover over different icons is to declare 'actions', every single time, I have to hover.                                                                 
                 actions = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(IconToHover)
                 actions.perform()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is following: you hover over a warning icon and get the tool tip. After that you find next element and mouse is trying to move. At this moment your current tooltip disappears and DOM is changed and you are getting StaleElementReferenceException.

Solution: let's move mouse to another element between moving from one icon to another one or try to repeat your steps several times.

Comment: Tried move_to_element.perform() multiple times for another element, before hovering over warnng icon, no luck :(